# Relocate second column of table below first for mobile version

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to relocate second column of table right below first column. I am using html table.  Now it [looks like that]: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjWBG.png) or [live site](http://ozon705.com/eng.html#bussines). But on mobile version it still keeps those 2 columns! How can I put second column below first?
HTML code you can open by the link in the start of article  (on the site it's in services for business, table) or look here:

HTML:

```css
.TableOfReasons {
    position: relative;
    left: 0%;
    right: 100%;
}
table {
    background-color: transparent;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table class="TableOfReasons">
   <!--One block-->
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-title"><h4>Odours elimination</h4></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-title"><h4>Communal service</h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-img"><image src="images/1.jpg" width="250px"></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-img"><image src="images/5.png" height="167px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=removing-smell&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=communal-service&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td>
    </tr>
    <!--End of one block-->

    <!--One block-->
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-title"><h4>Stimulation of avian growth <br> and prevention of infectious diseases </h4></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-title"><h4>Stimulation of animal <br> growth and prevention of infectious diseases </h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-img"><image src="images/3.jpg" height="167px"></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-img"><image src="images/2.jpg" width="250px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=birds&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=animals&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td>
    </tr>
    <!--End of one block-->

    <!--One block-->
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-title"><h4>Greenhouses</h4></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-title"><h4>Smell at a bar, restaurant, hotel etc.</h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-img"><image src="images/6.jpg" width="250px"></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-img"><image src="images/4.jpg" width="250px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=plants&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=smell-in-public-place&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td>
    </tr>
    <!--End of one block-->
    <!--One block-->
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-title"><h4>Beekeeping</h4></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-title"><h4>A the gym</h4></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-img"><image src="images/8.jpg" width="250px"></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-img"><image src="images/7.jpg" width="250px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=bees&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td>
      <td class="right-clmn feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=at-gym&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td>
    </tr>
    <!--End of one block-->

</table>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @caramba I don't know how to put HTML here. StackOverflow just output it, but no code!

Comment: You can edit your question, in the editor there is an icon to add code. If you don't find it, there is also a question mark `?` on the right of the editor. Use it, it will show help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the data in two different tables (one for the data on the left and one for the data on the right, otherwise exactly the same) and change the css for `.TableOfReasons` to this:

```
.TableOfReasons {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

then you need to add the html `<meta>` tag in the head:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and then use this css to change them both to `display: block;` when the screen changes width;

```
@media screen and(max-width: 600px) {
  .TableOfReasons {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

### DEMO:

```css
.TableOfReasons {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  display: inline-block;
}
table {
  background-color: transparent;
}
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media screen and(max-width: 600px) {
  .TableOfReasons {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<table class="TableOfReasons">
  <!--One block-->
  <tr><td class="feature-title"><h4>Odours elimination</h4></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="feature-img"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=removing-smell&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td></tr>
  <!--End of one block-->
  <!--One block-->
  <tr><td class="feature-title"><h4>Stimulation of avian growth <br> and prevention of infectious diseases</h4></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="feature-img"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=birds&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td></tr>
  <!--End of one block-->
  <!--One block-->
  <tr><td class="feature-title"><h4>Greenhouses</h4></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="feature-img"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=plants&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td></tr>
  <!--End of one block-->
  <!--One block-->
  <tr><td class="feature-title"><h4>Beekeeping</h4></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="feature-img"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=bees&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td></tr>
  <!--End of one block-->
</table>
<table class="TableOfReasons">
  <!--One block-->
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-title"><h4>Communal service</h4></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-img"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=communal-service&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td></tr>
  <!--End of one block-->
  <!--One block-->
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-title"><h4>Stimulation of animal<br>growth and prevention of infectious diseases</h4></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-img"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=animals&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td></tr>
  <!--End of one block-->
  <!--One block-->
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-title"><h4>Smell at a bar, restaurant, hotel etc.</h4></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-img"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=smell-in-public-place&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td></tr>
  <!--End of one block-->
  <!--One block-->
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-title"><h4>A the gym</h4></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-img"></td></tr>
  <tr><td class="right-clmn feature-button"><a href="/more-page.php?language=en&name=at-gym&link_back=/eng.html&block=bussines"><button class="more_btn">More</button></a></td></tr>
  <!--End of one block-->
</table>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/AquatuzMagnus/pen/XRvNPj)

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .TableOfReasons table tr{
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
    }

    .TableOfReasons table td{
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        clear:block;
    }
}
```

try this

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help!

Comment: than use bootstrap grid check the link

https://codepen.io/re5ive/pen/MmNbxK?editors=1100

Comment: In that case, how to make it equal? Because in `table` it was automatically!  Screenshot (on Google Drive): https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5rEChnosxq3VVpQUUpuanZpYkU