# css: display column as row in mobile view

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to display table column as row, when someone open page in mobile (less than 480px).

This is my table structure.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .main td {
    display: table-row;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
In desktop View
</p>
<table class="main">
<tr>
  <td>R1 Col 1</td>
  <td>R1 Col 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>R2 Col 1</td>
  <td>R2 Col 2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>R3 Col 1</td>
  <td>R3 Col 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I tried to do using css like.

```
@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .main td {
    display: table-row;
  }
}
```

But it is not working. In Mobile view I want output like this, Second column should display below first column.

**Note: I can't change table to div.**

This is my expected output:
[image]

Comment: Instead of `table`, you can use bootstrap to achieve this.

Comment: you cannot move a **td** from one **tr** to another by css, you can use 2 tables 1 for mobile view and 1 for desktop. and use `display:block/none;`

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: I have only option to use table & apply some css.

Comment: WIth your current html it's almost impossible ( it may be possible with some weird stuff with position absolute but i totally advice against that in this situation ) . What you would need is to get the 2nd td from each row out of the row and move it below. Which is not possible with just html and css. You need to either change html structure and use flexbox ( or cssgrid ) . Or rethink the requirement. Or it might be possible with javascript.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai why bootstrap ? why not directly flexbox ? why load an entire library for 2 lines of css ?

Comment: @Mihai Yep. agree with you

Comment: @MihaiT: I can use javascript, and It is fixed that I can only 2 column, but row can be 3-6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Responsive vertical/horizontal heading table with toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64299230/responsive-vertical-horizontal-heading-table-with-toggle)

Comment: I have a question, why dont you manage it with `grid` instead of a table ? It would be much easier to manage

Comment: @MaxiGui: Actually html is generated from [froala-editor](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor). And It does not allow to insert `div` I can insert only `table`.  [froala-jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tLjnse6v/)

Comment: ok then check this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279628/relocate-second-column-of-table-below-first-for-mobile-version

Comment: Base on the first link, I sent you, you can make it with js anyway or you can even get the whole normal table and duplicate one for mobile then you just display:none the one you wish

Comment: `tr {display:contents}` will allow every cells to be styled as they where sibblings, flex or grid on the parent of tr, will allow to use order to swap their position. CSS can help here for such a simple table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to break the table-layout via resets on display.

grid or flex can then allow you to reorder your elements

example

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .main tbody {
    display: grid; 
  }
  .main tr {
    display: contents;
    border:solid red
  }
  .main td {
    display: block;
  }
  .main tr td + td {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
  In desktop View
</p>
<table class="main">
  <tr>
    <td>R1 Col 1</td>
    <td>R1 Col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R2 Col 1</td>
    <td>R2 Col 2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>R3 Col 1</td>
    <td>R3 Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

explanation :

the browser will generate a `tbody` wrapper, you can reset display from than one and keep the  table display behavior on the `<table>`element so it keeps shrinking. Let's make that tbody a grid (defaut of `display:grid` is to draw a single column).

`tr` are in the way, `display:contents` will remove them virtually, so the cells (`td`) can be *(virtually)* direct child of `tbody` and be reorder via .. `order`. You can give here via `tr >:nth-child(x){order:X;}` an order to each cells.

ressource:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

> display **`contents`**
>
> These elements don't produce a specific box by themselves. They are replaced by their pseudo-box and their child boxes. Please note that the CSS Display Level 3 spec defines how the contents value should affect "unusual elements" — elements that aren’t rendered purely by CSS box concepts such as replaced elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the table structure then it is very difficult achieve the desired result. But if it is fixed row and column then you can use some CSS trick to bring the result.

You can reduce the browser width and see the below snippet.

```
 @media(max-width: 480px) {
   .main td{
     margin-top:63px
   }
   .main td:last-child {    
     position:absolute;
     left:8px;    
   }
}
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .main td{
    margin-top:63px
  }
  .main td:last-child {    
    position:absolute;
    left:8px;    
  }
}
```

```html
<p>
In desktop View
</p>
<table class="main">
  <tr>
    <td>R1 Col 1</td>
    <td>R1 Col 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R2 Col 1</td>
    <td>R2 Col 2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>R3 Col 1</td>
    <td>R3 Col 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/ue5yawoj/)

Answer (score 0):

adding display block to td and tr will force them to behave like block level element, try if it works for you

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

@media(max-width: 480px) {
  .main tr, .main td {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="main">
<tr>
  <td>R1 Col 1</td>
  <td>R1 Col 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>R2 Col 1</td>
  <td>R2 Col 2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>R3 Col 1</td>
  <td>R3 Col 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not expected out. Please see the attached image in question

Comment: ohh I did'nt saw the numbering in the image, this wont work in this way